# Как перенаправиться на другую страницу в html?

Tags: html, redirect

Я знаю как перенаправиться в javascript с помощью `window.location = "";`.
Как сделать это в html?

Comment: У тебя какой браузер? Google Chrome? Opera? Другой?

Answer (score 4):

наверное самый простой способ:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='http://new-website.com'" />
```

Атрибут `content` – это задержка перед тем, как браузер перенаправляет на новую страницу, так что мы присвоили ему значение в 0 секунд.

Comment: Это перенапрявляет в браузере а не в html

Comment: что в вашем понимании перенаправить в html?

Comment: Окошечко с сайтом которое находится на каком-то сайте

Answer (score 4):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="seconds;URL-to-redirect">
```

Пример - через 5 секунд автоматически будете перенаправлены на https://www.google.com

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; https://www.google.com">
```

Answer (score 2):

Простое перенаправление php:

```
<?php
    header('Location:http://newcoder.ru/cat/web/');
    exit;
?>
```

Простое перенаправление HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Кнопка" onClick='location.href="http://yandex.ru/"'>
```

Answer (score 2):

вы наверное про это окошко с сайтом

`<ifarme style="position:fixed;left:0px;top:0px;width:100%;height:100%;" src="http://site.host"></iframe>`

Comment: Спасибо. Кстати как увеличить это окошко?

Comment: `<iframe width="10%" height="10%" src="http://site" />`

Comment: окошко прямоугольное а не квадратное

Comment: при width="1000%" height="1000%" окошко вообще очень длинное

Comment: @LGPvS интересно, с чего бы вдруг... Может потому что вы ставите его в 10 раз больше чем 100%?

Comment: Зайди на сайт multiplayerpiano.com, потом подожди и введи в консоль это: MPP.client.emit("notification", { title: "Browser", html: '<iframe width="1000%" height="1000%" src="http://www.multiplayerpiano.com" />', duration: -1});

Comment: я проценты от балды поставил, откуда мне знать какой тип окошка у вас))

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="http://your link here">Click me</a>
```